# How to apply real-time kline data to trading view chart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, charts, rxjs, tradingview-api

I'm implementing a trading view chart, everything is functional except the real-time data.
Here is the TradingViewChart component:

```
...
import TradingView from "../../../charting_library/charting_library.standalone.js"
import { dataFeedObject } from "./api"

const TradingViewChart = () => {
  const tickersData = useSelector((state) => state.marketTickers.value)
  const selectedMarket = useSelector((state) => state.selectedMarket.value)
  const markets = useSelector((state) => state.marketList.value)
  const klineData = useSelector((state) => state.kline)
  const datafeed = dataFeedObject(TradingViewChart, markets)

  useEffect(() => {
    const widgetOptions = {
      allow_symbol_change: false,
      autosize: true,
      calendar: true,
      hide_legend: false,
      save_image: true,
      client_id: "tradingview.com",
      custom_css_url: "/chartStyles.css",
      debug: true,
      details: true,
      library_path: "/charting_library/",
      symbol: selectedMarket.id ?? "btcusdt",
      datafeed,
    }
    window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget(widgetOptions)
  }, [theme])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (klineData && klineData.last.time !== klineData.pre_last.time) {
      datafeed.onRealtimeCallback(klineData)
    }
  }, [klineData])
```

Next, is the datafeed object:

```
export const dataFeedObject = (tradingChart, markets) => {
    const dataFeed = {
        onReady: (cb) => {
            setTimeout(() => cb(config), 0)
        },
        searchSymbols: (
            userInput,
            exchange,
            symbolType,
            onResultReadyCallback
        ) => {
            const symbols = markets.map((m) => ({
                symbol: m.id,
                full_name: m.name,
                description: m.name,
                exchange: window.env.name || "Exchange",
                ticker: m.id,
                type: "bitcoin",
                currency_code: m.quote_unit.toUpperCase(),
            }))
            setTimeout(() => onResultReadyCallback(symbols), 0)
        },
        resolveSymbol: (
            symbolName,
            onSymbolResolvedCallback,
            onResolveErrorCallback
        ) => {
            // expects a symbolInfo object in response
            const symbol = markets.find(
                (m) => m.id === symbolName || m.name === symbolName
            )

            if (!symbol) {
                return setTimeout(
                    () => onResolveErrorCallback("Symbol not found"),
                    0
                )
            }

            const symbolStub = {
                name: symbol.name,
                currency_code: symbol.quote_unit.toUpperCase(),
                description: "",
                type: "bitcoin",
                session: "24x7",
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                ticker: symbol.id,
                minmov: 1,
                pricescale: Math.pow(10, symbol.price_precision),
                has_intraday: true,
                intraday_multipliers: [
                    "1"
                ],
                supported_resolutions: [
                    "1"
                ],
                volume_precision: symbol.amount_precision,
                data_status: "streaming",
            }
            return setTimeout(() => onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolStub), 0)
        },
        getTimescaleMarks: async (
            symbolInfo,
            from,
            to,
            onDataCallback,
            resolution
        ) => {
            if (tradingChart.tvWidget && tradingChart.tvWidget.activeChart) {
                const range = tradingChart.tvWidget.activeChart().getVisibleRange()
                const period = tradingChart.tvWidget.activeChart().resolution()
                store.dispatch(changeResolution(period))
                store.dispatch({ type: CHANGE_KLINE_RESOLUTION })
            }
        },
        getBars(
            symbolInfo,
            resolution,
            periodParams,
            onHistoryCallback,
            onErrorCallback
        ) {
            return _getMarketKline(
                symbolInfo.ticker || symbolInfo.name.toUpperCase(),
                resolution,
                periodParams.from,
                periodParams.to,
                (data) => {
                    const transformedData = data.map((item) => ([
                        Math.floor(item[0] / 1000), // Convert milliseconds to seconds
                        parseFloat(item[1]),
                        parseFloat(item[2]),
                        parseFloat(item[3]),
                        parseFloat(item[4]),
                        parseFloat(item[5])
                    ]))
                    const bars = transformedData.map(klineArrayToObject)
                        const bars = data.map(klineArrayToObject)
                        return onHistoryCallback(bars, {
                            noData: false,
                        })
                },

                (e) => {
                    return onHistoryCallback([], {
                        noData: true,
                    })
                }
            )
        },
        subscribeBars: (
            symbolInfo,
            resolution,
            onRealtimeCallback,
            subscribeUID,
            onResetCacheNeededCallback
        ) => {
            dataFeed.onRealtimeCallback = (kline) => {
                if (kline) {
                onRealtimeCallback(kline.last)
                }
            }

            const marketId = symbolInfo.ticker
            const periodString = periodMinutesToString(
                resolutionToSeconds(resolution)
            )
            window.console.log("PERIOD_STRING", periodString)
            store.dispatch(changeResolution(periodString))
            store.dispatch({ type: CHANGE_KLINE_RESOLUTION })
            tradingChart.currentKlineSubscription = {
                marketId,
                periodString,
            }
        },
        unsubscribeBars: (subscribeUID) => {
            const { marketId, periodString } =
                tradingChart.currentKlineSubscription

            tradingChart.currentKlineSubscription = {}
        },
        onRealtimeCallback: (kline) => {
            if (kline) {
                const transformedData = kline
                console.log("New kline data received:", transformedData)
            }
        },
    }
    return dataFeed
}
```

Additionally, this is a part of my websocketsaga, where I'm adding the kline data to a state:

```
    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      const tickers = JSON.parse(event.data)
      switch (key) {
        case `btcusdt.kline-1m`:
          if (subscribedMarket !== currentSubscribedMarket) {
            currentSubscribedMarket = subscribedMarket
            emitter(clearKline()) // Clear the kline array if market changed
          }
          emitter(addKline(tickers[`btcusdt.kline-1m`]))
          break
        default:
          break
      }
    }
```

I can see the "New kline data received:" being logged to the console, but the graph stays still, no points are being appended. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. As you may have noticed, you've asked your question 4h ago and not a single answer yet. It doesn't mean there will never be, but to explain why you may not get any answer IMO: You haven't made enough efforts to synthesise your answer. I know it's a lot of work to pin point the zone of the code that doesn't work. But if you shift that work on people who could answer instead of doing it yourself, you drastically reduce your chances to have replies. You've shared **400** lines of code. I'd suggest you try to trim it down to the bare minimum and provide a repro on stackblitz.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).